# How can i start the generation in emftext via ant?

Tags: eclipse, ant, dsl, eclipse-emf

I have an emftext example project in eclipse setted up. It works fine if i start the "generate text resources" via context menu of eclipse at the *.cs file. But now i would like to change the project in a maven project. With the pom.xml and tycho i could build the eclipse-plugin successful. But i could not generate the text resources (creating of editor projects) via maven or ant.

In http://www.emftext.org/EMFTextGuide.php#x1-120002.3.2 the manual means ant will be support it out of the box whithin eclipse. But it does not work at my pc. The ant task

```
<emftext.GenerateTextResource>
```

its unknow to ant in eclipse.

Maybe i must be define it via taskdef but which *.jar i must be include or which class or so?

Thanks for hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i have found the solution at a example code of the emftext project.
I must enable the eclipse external tool setting for Ant "Run in the same JRE as the workspace". Now it works fine within the eclipse and the transform to work in maven should be simple.

Here is the url point to the source of the hint:
http://svn-st.inf.tu-dresden.de/svn/reuseware/tags/20100922-emftext-1.3.1-jamopp-1.2.1/Build/org.reuseware/build-text-resources.xml.template

Here is the original hint text:

```
<!-- Define the EMF Generate Resource task. To have this task available, the plugin
org.emftext.sdk.ant must be available in the classpath. To ensure this the external   
tools configuration needs to have the setting "Run in the same JRE as the workspace"
enabled. -->
```